# Would it be possible to negotiate a key of 128 or 256 bits strength using Merkle puzzles?

Tags: protocol-design, key-exchange, reference-request, history

One can be fascinated by the simplicity of the schemes created by Ralf Merkle; like the Merkle tree or his key negociation protocol over an insecure channel.

Wikipedia has some material on "Merkle puzzles"
([wikipedia_page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%27s_Puzzles))
and his seminal paper can be found online
([article_pdf](http://www.merkle.com/1974/Puzzles1975.12.07.pdf)).

But, could this venerable construction be put to use in order
to reach nowadays security strength requirements (i.e. a key
of at least 128 bits strength, or even 256 bits for the real paranoids out there).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The complexity required for the attacker to break the scheme is at maximum quadratic in the security parameter $n$. It is not enough for a secure cryptographic protocol where you want exponential complexity to break the scheme.

Say $n$ is the difficulty of solving the puzzles and $m$ is the number of puzzles. Alice needs to solve one puzzle in time $O(n)$ but Bob will need to look in his puzzles to find the correct key. He needs roughly $O(m)$ time. The scheme has then $O(n+m)$ time complexity.

For breaking the scheme, Eve can brute force all the puzzles, she then needs $O(nm)$ time complexity. If you want to have this complexity be around $2^{128}$ you need to send an incredible amount of puzzles and/or puzzles too hard.